# Maven Objenesis related build issue

Tags: maven, build

I am facing this issue while doing mvn install

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
Project ID: org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0
Reason: Cannot find parent: org.objenesis:**objenesis-parent** for project:    
org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0 for project org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0
```

I looked up every maven repo like mvnrepository, repo1.maven, etc and cannot find this objenesis parent Jar anywhere. Even the Objenesis site has only objenesis Jar but no parent Jar.

Is the objenesis parent Jar required ? (I am mocking some classes (not interfaces) using JMock, hence the dependency of JMock Legacy on Objenesis)

Am I missing something in pom config so that project can build without objenesis parent Jar?

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
        <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The peopl have made a mistake, cause the 1.0 parent does not exist but for 1.1 and 1.2 it's existing in Maven Central. May be you should use version 1.1 instead of 1.0 ?

Comment: But the jmock-legacy of JMock 2.5.1 (the latest) list objenesis 1.0 as the dependency and is also included. Anyway, I put objenesis 1.2 jar (I am not able to find parent Jar for this too) and it is working fine now.